# What package is used here to produce the beautiful summary?

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents

[image: Summary]

I have already finished writing a book and I would like to produce this kind of table of contents as a summary.

Comment: It's basically just the `tcolorbox` package. The documentation source should be on your system: `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pas-cours/pas-cours.tex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code fragment for the table of contents of the `pas-math` package, available on [this page](https://www.mathweb.fr/web/latex-packages-personnels) of the author's site.

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[toc]
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{toc}
\makeatother
\end{tcolorbox}
```